# Keywords doubling up issue in PDF generated by TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

The PDF files created by the TCPDF are very good but for some reasons the *Keywords* are doubled when view from Adobe Reader properties. What could go wrong here? Below is the code:

```
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('AR Conolly and Company Lawyers');
$pdf->SetTitle('Benchmark');
$pdf->SetSubject('Benchmark Publication');
$pdf->SetKeywords('law firm, cases, publication, courts, sydney, australia, daily, weekly, insurance, construction, banking, radio, bechmark tv');
```

Comment: What version of TCPDF are you using? I see a [bug fix regarding "double keywords" in version 5.9.135](https://github.com/tcpdf-clone/tcpdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG.TXT#LC703), but I'm not sure if that's relevant here. [Also found this](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/647/).

Comment: Hi Showdev, thanks for you response.

I am using Version: 6.0.099
Release date: 2014-11-15. This version should have fixed the double keywords issue but not happening in my case. I m still not sure what might have caused it. Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I use version TCPDF 6.2.26. and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I found that the function "_putXMP()" in tcpdf.php have put the keyword twice in line 9539 and line 9562. Commenting either line will result proper keywords in PDF properties.